# ASP.NET MVC specific question - Should this be on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suitable-question

Looking at this question:

> [How do you avoid XSS vulnerabilities in ASP.Net (MVC)?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-do-you-avoid-xss-vulnerabilities-in-asp-net-mvc)

I would have said that the question was better asked on StackOverflow rather than on Pro Webmasters - it's not very Web Mastery, and is more programming orientated? I had a quick look through the sample questions in the commissioning, and didn't find many like that.

Comment: It would be on-topic if it was language-agnostic. i.e. `How do you avoid XSS vulnerabilities?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would agree.  Seems like the same deal as [this jQuery question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60/how-do-i-write-a-plugin-in-jquery) to me.

Answer (score 3):

If the question was more like "How can I determine how these people are getting in, I'm using ASP.Net" , it would be good here .. or perhaps severfault?

I think an early and critical consensus to be reached is how much overlap will be permitted. If you think about it, a good number of questions that would be appropriate here would also (conceivably) be appropriate for SF.

Comment: Agree, *some* questions can overlap. It's a similar situation to URL rewrite (htaccess) questions, which can work on either SO or SF -- and now this site. There is a bit of grey area. In these cases I say leave it on the site it originated unless there's some compelling bit of evidence it should go elsewhere.

Comment: I wonder if we'll be able to tell which marginal questions are appropriate by the quality of answers they get.  (ie. if they're not getting great answers, then we don't have the expertise -- they're not general webmaster questions -- and they should be moved).